# Inserting data from database into table. LAST COLUMN NOT WORKING

Tags: php, html, singlestore

My code is working correctly except the last table data (data 7) is not inserting and showing up blank.

```
<table id="History" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
          <a href="export.php"> Export To Excel </a> 

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First <br> Name</th>
            <th>Last <br> Name</th>
            <th>Competition <br> Name</th>
            <th>Competition Level</th>
            <th>Dance Name</th>
            <th>Number of Competitors</th>
            <th>Dancer's Placement</th>
            <th>Dancer's Score</th>
            <th>1st Place Score</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
          <?php
          $sql = "SELECT `dancer_name`,`dancer_lastname`,`comp_name`,`competition_level1`, `dance_name1`, `number_competitors1`, `dancer_placement1`, `dancer_score1`, `1stpl_score1` FROM `report` WHERE name = '$name'";
          $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 

          //if($res==FALSE){
          //die('there was an error running query [' . $con->error . ']');
          //  }

          while($data=mysqli_fetch_row($res)){
              echo '
              <tr>
              <td>'.$data[0].'</td>
              <td>'.$data[1].'</td>
              <td>'.$data[2].'</td>
              <td>'.$data[3].'</td>
              <td>'.$data[4].'</td>
              <td>'.$data[5].'</td>
              <td>'.$data[6].'</td>
              <td>'.$data[7].'</td>
              </tr> 
              ';  
    }

?>  
</table>
```

data 0-6 shows up fine, but 7 is always blank. Please tell me, what's wrong with my code?

Comment: you should use mysqli_fetch_assoc instead of mysqli_fetch_row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first suggest you **use php function var_dump($data) to shown content inside it**. Later you have to **check if index seven [7] is null or empty**, *if so check in your table database to make sure if record exist*... **If exist, check your query to make sure if properties are correct**.

This could helpful:

> [Documentation PHP var_dump](http://php.net/manual/es/function.var-dump.php)
>
> **Bonus**: I suggest you use [mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) instead mysqli_fetch_row, because you can "***use associative indices, using the field names of the result set as keys***", making your code more maintainable and legibility.

For example:

```
$data["dancer_name"]; // instead $data[0]
```

Comment: I used mysqli_fetch_array instead, and now i'm getting this error?

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'stpl_score1' (T_STRING), expecting ']' in /home/hqwkui898g3u/public_html/feishistory.php on line 222

this is line 222 <td>'.$row[1stpl_score1].'</td>

Comment: Okay I realized that the number 1 in "1stpl_score1" was the issue so I changed it to "firstplace_score". after making that change the table IS working but for some reason im getting this error for all the table data '<td>'....Notice: Use of undefined constant dancer_name - assumed 'dancer_name' in /home/hqwkui898g3u/public_html/feishistory.php on line 214

Comment: Never mind! I fixed it. I forgot to put "" around firstplace_score. Thank you, it works perfectly now!